# How to connect mongodb with nodejs in same (single) droplet in digitalocean

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, digital-ocean, mongoose-schema

I tried to connect mongodb and node server api app (Request URL https://services.suriyashopping.com/api/menu-list) in same droplet. The nodejs server app and mongodb running in single droplet and server placed in sub domain. I have mention my db connection code below and i got conncetion success while run server by "nodemon app.js". But after then i made request from client to server, then i got some not authorized error. One more query is why DB and related collections not generated automatically while run server via Ubuntu terminal "nodemon app.js". i have use nginix server block to point sub domain.If i run server in my local machine DB and related collection will generated. but here it's not generated.

NodeJs, Express, mongodb, mongoose, linux 16.04, nginix for server block to point sub domain

## MongoDB connection code

I tried droplet ip as local IP "127.0.0.1" and also my droplet "142.93.215.18"

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@dropletip:27017/SURIYAShoppingDB', 
  { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      console.log('MongoDB connection succeeded.');
    }
  })
```

## Expected result

I tried this request url to get response (if any available)
 https://services.suriyashopping.com/api/menu-list

## Actual result

```
{ MongoError: not authorized on SURIYAShoppingDB to execute command { find: "maincategories", filter: { status: "true", active_status: "true" }, projection: { __v: false, catgoryImage: false, active_status: false, status: false, createdAt: false, updatedAt: false }, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false }
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/www/services.suriyashopping.com/html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at processMessage (/var/www/services.suriyashopping.com/html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:364:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/services.suriyashopping.com/html/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:533:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  ok: 0,
  errmsg:
   'not authorized on SURIYAShoppingDB to execute command { find: "maincategories", filter: { status: "true", active_status: "true" }, projection: { __v: false, catgoryImage: false, active_status: false, status: false, createdAt: false, updatedAt: false }, returnKey: false, showRecordId: false }',
  code: 13,
  name: 'MongoError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
(node:28975) DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. Use collection.countDocuments or collection.estimatedDocumentCount instead
```

### My UFW status

```
mydroplet:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
27017                      ALLOW       142.93.215.18
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to grant your users access to that database and or find function through mongo.

Comment: i didn't get you can you give me clear guidance

Comment: If you do `db.getCollection('system.users').find({})` that should list all of your db users - look through that list and find the user your having problems with and copy that section out, remove the password/key/salt etc and then [edit] your question to include it. I think your either missing a roll, or have added the user to the wrong place.

Comment: Nope. Actually i don't have db in mongodb in digital ocean. If i run nodemon app.js, then db and related collections will generated. but here i don't know why it's not created. else i need to create entire db manually in cmd

Comment: Oh - so your saying you don't even have the database setup and working yet then?!!? I think when you run the script on your test machine you have the db already setup and working in the first place. Sorry its been a long day for me so maybe I'm missing something silly. To find out why the script isn't working you would need to post enough for an MCVE.

Comment: I have only setup mongodb with secure with firewall. But i got MongoError: not authorized on SURIYAShoppingDB to execute command while tried to save in that. Note: I'm not create any database like SURIYAShoppingDB in mongodb. what i need to do or anything need to update in my droplet UFW